Converting to PDF fails due to xelatex not being found
I use the Jupyter Notebook through Anaconda on the browser and want to convert my notebook to PDF.
I am hitting the error where xelatex is not found however, I do have it installed because when I run xelatex --version on my terminal I get the following output:
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024/Homebrew)
kpathsea version 6.4.0
Copyright 2024 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.

Further investigation revealed that Jupyter does not add my system path.
What is the best way I can get my system path added to Jupyter so that I can convert my notebooks to PDF.
Many thanks.
